# What does this C++ template macro mean?

Tags: c++, templates, macros, c++14, variadic-functions

Can somebody please break down this for me? I know macros, and I am fairly familiar with templates, but I have no idea what the author is expressing with this. What's the intended usage, why is it written like this? What are we defining to be what here? How and why does one use this?

```
#define MY_CLASS(RET_TYPE, ... )\
    template<typename Derived>\
    __VA_ARGS__\
    RET_TYPE my_class_impl<Derived>
```

And I also have something like

```
MY_CLASS( )::my_class_impl( int arg_id )
```

And I also see

```
template<typename Derived>
class my_class_impl
```

I heard from a colleague that this is a case of CRTP (curiously recurring template pattern), but he did not have any more specific insights.

Also, I see it used subsequently as follows:

```
MY_CLASS(some_type)::find_desired_val(int x) {
// some code
}
```

So, the macro is used to substitute method signatures for the class `my_class_impl` when actually implementing them?

Comment: What is `my_class_impl`?

Comment: The `typename Derived` makes it look like a CRTP mashed inside a macro. What sensible arguments could be provided for `RET_TYPE` and `...`, and why the macro is called without any, I don't know.

Comment: @Quentin: `__decltype(dllexport)` comes to mind. But that's an MSVC++ extension.

Comment: @MSalters Oooh. IIRC MSVC also has an extension for calling macros with missing parameters.

Comment: Is this an MSVC specific question then?

Comment: this code doesn't make much sense, to me at least

Comment: No, definitely not specific to MSVC, but thanks for the comments. Using C++14.

Comment: also, I think this is a legitimate question. The OP saw the code and seeks to understand it. And seeing as it is convoluted at best, I don't see a reason to close it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's used to define member functions of `my_class_impl<Derived>`.

```
MY_CLASS(void)::member(Bar b) {}
```

Expands to :

```
template <typename Derived>
void my_class_impl<Derived>::member(Bar b) {}
```

The variadic macro arguments can be used for various (standard or not) attributes, such as [`__declspec(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dabb5z75.aspx), [`[[...]]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes), etc. For example:

```
MY_CLASS(void, __declspec(dllexport))::foo();
```

Expands to :

```
template <typename Derived>
__declspec(dllexport) void my_class_impl<Derived>::foo() {}
```

The `MY_CLASS()::my_class_impl(int arg_id)`, thanks to a compiler extension that allows missing macro parameters (present on MSVC, as well as Clang and GCC, I was mistaken), expands to a constructor :

```
template <typename Derived>
/* nothing */ my_class_impl<Derived>::my_class_impl(int arg_id) {}
```

It is also quite an ugly macro. Not only is it hard to understand, it hides away very mundane stuff, and breaks if you ever try to return a type containing a comma (`std::map<int, int>`).

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes sense. One more detail, what if _VA_ARGS_ actually stands for a couple of extra arguments? How will the method signature be expanded then? Can you please provide concrete example?

Comment: @BaronYugovich added example.

Answer (score 2):

The `RET_TYPE` is a hint that this is a function, and `MY_CLASS` in particular hints at member functions. Those can be declared `static` as well.

Less common would be `[[noreturn]]` or `[[deprecated]]` which are C++14 attributes.

The `<Derived>` part is pretty irrelevant to this, class templates can have member functions just like classes can.

Comment: Well, yes, this is C++14.